# How I can make a configure AWS EC2 apache server

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

How I can make configure for an AWS EC2 apache instance server to do the flowing:

Accepts incoming POSTs from subnets 149.154.160.0/20 and 91.108.4.0/22 on port 443, 80, 88, or 8443

Comment: Can you clarify. Is this question about how to setup security groups for the instance, or it can be assumed that SGs are correctly setup?

Comment: it's public question

Answer (score 0):

Attach a security group to the instance with four rules as follows (in `Inbound rules` section), one per port(443, 80, 88, 8443), four different rules like this for port 443 [image]

You can check more info at [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#:~:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20security,that%20allows%20all%20outbound%20traffic.)

Comment: i did all allow all traffic it's same or not?